# Why the passenger runs the web application process as user 'nobody' and group 'nogroup'

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger

Getting the error:

> Message from application: This web application process is being run as user 'nobody' and group 'nogroup' and must be able to access its application root directory '/root/dev/smartChat-service'. However, the parent directory '/root' has wrong permissions, thereby preventing this process from accessing its application root directory. Please fix the permissions of the directory '/root' first.

I think the user sandboxing is enabled according to [here](http://ttps://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/user_sandboxing.html).The passenger_user_switching is on and the nginx process have the root privileges:

```
root      4296  0.0  0.2 140220  4316 ?        Ss   12:10   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
root      4297  0.0  0.3 140524  6508 ?        S    12:10   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      4298  0.0  0.3 140524  6508 ?        S    12:10   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      4299  0.0  0.3 140524  6508 ?        S    12:10   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      4300  0.0  0.3 140524  6508 ?        S    12:10   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

And the /root/smartChat-service directory and the directories/files in it are owned by root:

```
rw-------  1 root root 3632 Sep  1 15:19 app.js
drw-------  2 root root 4096 Sep  1 15:19 bin
drw-------  3 root root 4096 Sep  3 08:56 config
-rw-------  1 root root  326 Sep  1 15:19 deploy_doc.sh
-rw-------  1 root root  419 Sep  1 15:19 gulpfile.js
drw-------  3 root root 4096 Sep  1 15:19 lib
drw-------  2 root root 4096 Sep  1 15:19 migrations
drw-------  2 root root 4096 Sep  1 15:19 models
drw------- 31 root root 4096 Sep  2 05:38 node_modules
-rw-------  1 root root 1015 Sep  1 15:19 package.json
drw-------  3 root root 4096 Sep  1 15:19 public
-rw-------  1 root root 1591 Sep  1 15:19 README.md
-rw-------  1 root root  168 Sep  1 15:19 redis_client.js
drw-------  3 root root 4096 Sep  1 15:19 routes
drw-------  6 root root 4096 Sep  1 15:19 test
-rw-------  1 root root  256 Sep  1 15:19 test.sh
drw-------  2 root root 4096 Sep  1 15:19 views
```

Wondering why still getting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, Passenger refuses to run your app as root. If your app.js is owned by root, Passenger insists on running it as `passenger_default_user` instead (which defaults to `nobody`). You really should `chown` your files to a user that is not root.